# How to retrieve truncating records (SQL Server) . Is it Feasible?

Tags: sql-server

I was getting in more details for Truncate Vs. Delete. Most differences are commonly observed /practiced in daily routine. However the one I would like to know is how to retrieve records removed by truncating.

I read that truncate command does not log transaction log for each row like delete does, instead it logs for deallocating of page.

So can I retrieve a truncated (and committed) record from a table?

e.g.

```
Truncate table Student_Record;
```

If I simply run this, can records from `Student_Record` be retrieved?

Comment: I only know pays solutions... for example [ApexSQL Recovery](https://www.apexsql.com/download.aspx?gclid=CjwKCAjw2_LcBRBYEiwA_XVBU5HjcZpzI0iVqKGSo0Yp8RfceDmspDDLWf_oQaJfqNVkaMK8Ow42uhoChUsQAvD_BwE) they have a trial who could get a percent of the data truncated.

Comment: Thanks @GeraldoDiaz . Does same lies with data deleted with Delete command ?  Or the fact that 'delete command generate log of every rows deletion';  does this make task comparatively feasible ?

Comment: Yes, sir. It also works recovering data removed using Delete statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. You will have to backup your data before doing the truncate.

According to the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/truncate-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> **TRUNCATE**
>
> Removes all rows from a table or specified partitions of a table,
>   without logging the individual row deletions. TRUNCATE TABLE is
>   similar to the DELETE statement with no WHERE clause; however,
>   TRUNCATE TABLE is faster and uses fewer system and transaction log
>   resources.

By not logging anything you are making a faster delete, saving space and thus not able to recover these items.

You can't even trigger any operations while doing the truncate:

> TRUNCATE TABLE cannot activate a trigger because the operation does
>   not log individual row deletions. For more information, see CREATE
>   TRIGGER (Transact-SQL).

Be careful when using truncate, if you want to retrieve deleted rows you would have to run a delete statement rather than the truncate and look at the logs.

**EDIT**

There are some solutions and tools that read from the data pages once the truncate has been executed. Data in the data pages is marked to be overwritten by new data. Tools like [ApexSQL](https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/rollback-truncate-operation-without-backups/) read these, thus letting you generate a recreation script for the truncated data. If this is executed immediately after running the truncate, you could recover the info.

**However**

If after you truncate, there are update, insert or delete operations, the data pages might be overwritten. If this happens, not even ApexSQL can help you.

Comment: you can include it in a transaction and roll it back. the part of the docs you quote is for Azure SQL Data Warehouse and Parallel Data Warehouse

Comment: @MartinSmith you are right, I've modified the answer. Thanks!